# Saving to CSV changes data from numbers to written dates

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013, csv

I Have an Excel file that contains data that change specific cells to a written date when saved as a CSV file....And I dont want that!

For instance "4000-03" in a cell will be  "mars-00"

conditions:
 1. Its not possible to add prefix or suffix because of # character limits in the cells
 2. I need the file as an Excel CSV due to import rules. No other files will work.
 3. It's not possible to post-process the cells.

Thanks/Christer

Comment: Is there a question in there?

Comment: Sry Updated :) @DBADon

Comment: It looks like in your locale, 4000-03 is a legitimate way to write March 4000, so Excel is interpreting it as a date.  Typically, when creating a CSV, the problem is the other way around (values formatted as a date get stored as the internal date number).  I'll need more coffee to think about an actual solution, but I can offer a workaround.  Build the CSV records in the spreadsheet by concatenating the component cells (one record per row).  That gives you control over how each value gets stored.  Then export that column to a CSV file.  (cont'd)

Comment: If the records would exceed cell character limits, just concatenate the problem cell with an adjacent cell and use that helper cell instead of the two columns when selecting what to export as CSV.  That lets you control how it is stored, and once that problem number is part of a character string, Excel won't try to reinterpret it.

Comment: Is it possible to `Format > Cells` and change the column type to `Text`?

Comment: @fixer1234 Your solution is a bit over my knowledge, but I will discuss that with a colleague and see if it's feasible. however, it's imperative that the numeric characters are intact when opening as a CSV. And with no extra characters or spaceing etc. Also the CVS will contain over 50k articles with a different setup. numeric, letters, mixed, special characters like "-" and with a cap for 16characters length in the cell. All  that is fixed. It's just the date problem left.

Comment: @David Lord  Yes, but it doesn't fix the date problem, Excel still interprets some cells as dates and replace them.

Comment: 4000-03 is a text string.  It's just a quirk that allows Excel to interpret it as a date (which gets stored as a number).  It isn't clear whether Excel is converting it to a date when it builds the CSV file, or it just isn't designating it as text, and then it's being converted to a date by Excel when it is imported because without it explicitly being designated as text, it could potentially be a date. Text can be forced to be interpreted as text by putting it in quotes, like "4000-03".  (cont'd)

Comment: When it is imported at the other end, the quotes are stripped off as part of importing the CSV, and it is recognized as text.  You can't just make the quotes part of the cell contents, though, because then they will be part of the cell contents.  But you can build the value for the CSV record by concatenating quote marks around the cell value.  Exactly how to do that will depend on the constraints of your spreadsheet.